# JavaScript Duck Hunt bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, web

I am trying to create a duck hunting game using JavaScript. The following code should move duck images from the left side to the right side of the canvas. There doesn't seem to be any syntax error but nothing happens when I test the code. I would appreciate any help.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var time = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
var ducs = [];
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);


// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
 bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/DHbackground.jpg";

// Duck image
var duckReady = false;
var duckImage = new Image();
duckImage.onload = function () {
 duckReady = true;
};
duckImage.src = "images/duck.png";

// Handle mouse and keyboard controls
var mouseDown = {
 x: 0,
 y: 0,
};

function getClickPosition(e) {
    mouseDown.x = e.clientX;
    mouseDown.y = e.clientY;
};

canvas.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

var reset = function(){
 // To do: resets the game 
  };

// Draw everything
var render = function () {
 if (bgReady) {
  ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
 }
 time = time-1;
 if (time < 0){ 
  var duck = {
      cur_X: 0,
      cur_Y: Math.round(Math.random()*500),
      final_X: 500,
      final_Y: Math.round(Math.random()*500),
  };
  time = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
  ducs.push(duck);
  for (var i = 0; i < ducs.Lenght; i++){
   ctx.drawImage(duckImage, ducs[i].cur_X, ducs[i].cur_Y);
   console.log(ducs[i].cur_X);
  }
 }

 // Score
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
 ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
 ctx.textAlign = "left";
 ctx.textBaseline = "top";
 ctx.fillText("Ducks killed: " + 3, 10, 10);
};

var update = function (modifier) {
 for (var i = 0; i < ducs.Lenght; i++){
  ducs[i].cur_X = ducs[i].cur_X + Math.floor(((ducs[i].final_X - ducs[i].cur_X)/500)+1);
  ducs[i].cur_Y = ducs[i].cur_Y + Math.floor(((ducs[i].final_Y - ducs[i].cur_Y)/500)+1);
  if (ducs[i].cur_X > 500){
   ducs.splice(i, 1);
  }
 }
};
 


// The main game loop
var main = function () {
 var now = Date.now();
 var delta = now - then;

 render();
 update(delta / 1000);

 then = now;

 // Request to do this again ASAP
 requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Duck Hunt Pandy</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="js/game.js"> </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should design your callbacks properly, rather than essentially polling for their state changes at the start.

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit? Read about producing a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

I found a typo:

`var update = function (modifier) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ducs.Lenght; i++){`

Length is spelled incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

First problem. You misspelled length.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ducs.length; i++){
```

Second is that you need to make sure to draw the ducks each time the loop runs.

```
if (time < 0){ 
    var duck = {
        cur_X: 0,
        cur_Y: Math.round(Math.random()*500),
        final_X: 500,
        final_Y: Math.round(Math.random()*400),
    };
    time = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    ducs.push(duck);        
}

for (var i = 0; i < ducs.length; i++){
    ctx.drawImage(duckImage, ducs[i].cur_X, ducs[i].cur_Y);
    console.log(ducs[i].cur_X);
}
```

third is that you need to remove the ducks when they reach the end (you were checking for 500, but their flight final was 400).

```
var duck = {
    cur_X: 0,
    cur_Y: Math.round(Math.random()*500),
    final_X: 500,
    final_Y: Math.round(Math.random()*400),
};

if (ducs[i].cur_X > 500){
    ducs.splice(i, 1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ygh6mfpw/6/

Edit: Fix for duck movement

Comment: Do you have any idea how to slow it down? I tried using:

setTimeout(main(), 4000);

but it is not working.

Comment: @MichalPándy Took a closer look and the problem is actually that you're only drawing the ducks when they're first added.

https://jsfiddle.net/ygh6mfpw/5/